# Why do successive calls to new[] not allocate contiguous memory?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, heap-memory

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. Here is my C++ code to see how memory is used.

```
int main() {
  int **ptr;

  ptr = new int* [2];
  cout << &ptr << " -> " << ptr << endl; 

  for (int r = 1; r <= 2; r++) {
    ptr[r-1] = new int [2 * r];
    cout << &ptr[r-1] << " -> " << ptr[r-1] << endl;

    for (int c = 0; c < 2 * r; c++) {       
        ptr[r-1][c] = r * c;
        cout << &ptr[r-1][c] << " -> " << ptr[r-1][c] << endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here is my output:

```
0x7fff09faf018 -> 0x1195010
0x1195010 -> 0x1195030
0x1195030 -> 0
0x1195034 -> 1
0x1195018 -> 0x1195050
0x1195050 -> 0
0x1195054 -> 2
0x1195058 -> 4
0x119505c -> 6
```

I expected the OS would allocate memory contiguously. So ptr[0][0] would be at 0x1195020 instead of 0x1195030!? What does OS use at 0x1195020 - 0x119502F, 0x1195038 - 0x0x119504F for?

Comment: You are not allocating memory directly from the OS.  The runtime manages its own heap, which in turn, is allocated from the OS.  There is no guarantee that successive calls to new() are contiguous.  Never assume that in your code.

Comment: If 'I thought the OS would allocate memory contiguously.', then why should you use ptr[r-1] but not just direct ptr + (offset 0x10 bytes) as ptr[r-1]?

Comment: Also, every time you `malloc()` memory or `new[]` an array, the runtime has to add some extra bytes to keep track of how much memory/how many objects were allocated, so when you later `free()` or `delete[]` the memory it knows how much to clean up.

Comment: I would suggest you to read about dynamic memory allocation on unix systems. This [article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/58e72888-6340-46ac-b488-d31aa4058e9c/entry/dynamic_memory_allocation_in_c4?lang=en) for example. Quote from the article: _When you malloc a block, it actually allocates a bit more memory than you asked for. This extra memory is used to store information such as the size of the allocated block, and a link to the next free/used block in a chain of blocks, and sometimes some "guard data"_

Comment: There's no guarantee that the first block will be allocated at a lower address than the second block — and the pattern of allocations may well depend on the sizes of the allocations (with bigger blocks being allocated separately from smaller blocks).  All you can safely assume is that the space allocated by one `new` won't overlap with any other currently allocated block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because:

1. Some space at the beginning and end of each block of allocated memory is often used for bookkeeping. (In particular, many allocators find it useful to store the size of the preceding/following blocks, or pointers to them, around there.)
2. The memory allocator may "round up" the size of an allocated block to make things easier for it. For instance, an allocation of 7 bytes will likely be rounded up to 8 bytes, if not even 16 or 32.
3. Blocks of memory may already be available in noncontiguous locations. (Keep in mind that the C runtime may have been making some memory allocations of its own before `main()` even runs.)
4. The allocator may have a plan in mind for laying out memory which would be ruined by putting the next block at the "next" address. (It may, for instance, have reserved that memory for allocations of a particular size.)
5. Why should it? There are no guarantees. Allocated memory could end up anywhere. (Well, almost.) Don't make any assumptions, just let memory go wherever the allocator says it'll go, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Also, some allocators segregate memory blocks based on size. This is done for various reasons, typically to minimize fragmentation.

Comment: Thanks. Added something to that effect.